# How do I stop Amazon Web Service's RDS from locking out connections during backups?

Tags: backup, mysql, amazon-web-services, locking, amazon-rds

I've been using RDS for years, and this only became an issue a few months ago. I was pulling my hair out trying to find the source of the issue... only to figure out it's suddenly RDS.

I've made no configuration changes or anything, but now I can see that when RDS does a backup of my MySQL 5.6.34 database, it is kicking off all the clients and doesn't accept connections and queries until it finishes.

https://forum.ghost.org/t/back-with-the-ghost-sites-failing-to-load-following-an-aws-rds-maintenance-backup-window/1983/3 I wound up finding a similar problem that someone is experiencing here, but with no solution to it figured out.

What changed and how do I resolve this?

Comment: RDS doesn't lock out connections, deny queries, or do anything unusual during backups, other than an I/O freeze and locks on tables in the mysql schema itself that are typically so brief that they are difficult to even observe happen... or, at least, it shouldn't.  Set `log_warnings` in the parameter group to "2" and see what appears in the error log before/during/after these events.  Consider also connecting manually before a backup and capturing the output of the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` before, during, and after.

Comment: Ah I did have a log, though this was before setting log_warnings=2. https://pastebin.com/H34FBmPi
Nothing in it stands out to be other than the long semaphore waits. It says that it crashes when shutting down, but I'm not seeing a reason why unless it'll come up with the changed warning level.

But regardless of it crashing, I'm not seeing anything to indicate why some clients aren't reconnecting when it finishes crashing and restarting, other than connection timing out on the clients' end.

Comment: Okay, that log file tells an interesting story.  `InnoDB: Warning: a long semaphore wait` is a warning that InnoDB waited an entirely unreasonable amount of time for a semaphore, which in physical servers often points to a hard drive on the brink of failure that is stalling on reads and/or writes but not throwing errors (or not throwing them yet), or a degraded RAID array... but RDS runs on EBS, making that a less likely possibility (or so it would seem).

Comment: Is this a t2 RDS instance? If so, you should start with your [`CPUCreditBalance` metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html) -- depleting that balance slows the CPU to a crawl, but RDS backups are volume snapshots, occurring outside the instance, so they don't consume CPU credits.  Still, that's my next question.  Is it a t2, and, if so, how does that metric look?

Comment: The CPU has always been under 5%, usually around 1%.
Anyway, it seems to have magically fixed itself about a week and a half ago without me changing anything. I'm guessing it was some disk issue at AWS.